# Why are these Mongoose findById, findOne, or find queries resolving to null, i.e. model.findOne({ _id: null }, {})?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have a NextJS project using Mongoose with two different databases in api endpoints. Using a connection from one to create a model I can retrieve all documents from the model with `model.find()` but any query beyond that returns nothing, i.e. `model.find({name: "abc"})` or `model.findById('foo')`, when I know there are matching results. Inspecting the mongoose debug logs shows that these queries are resolving any of the parameters I pass in as `null` so they return nothing.

I use `mongoose.createConnection(...)` to create to connections to each db and have created factory functions along with the schema definitions which take a connection and return a model something like:

```js
module.exports = (connection) => {
  const Cat = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String, default: ...customIdFunction... },
    name: {type: String, required: true}
  })
  return connection.models.Cat || connection.model('Cats', Cat)
}
```

`_id` is specified as a string because I'm creating a custom id instead of using the built in default. I've seen many other answers to similar questions where the answer is that they've imported some json and made string ids that should be mongoose ObjectIds, but I am specifically using string ids.

When I try to use this in my endpoint, I can initiate it with my connection ala `const Cat = CatFactory(connection)` and then I can retrieve all cats with `await Cat.find({})` but no find query will return anything but `[]` or `null`. For example, if I know I have a Cat with `_id` `FOOFOO` and `name` `Fluffy`:

```js
const allCats = await Cat.find({}); // returns all cats
const cat1 = await Cat.findById("FOOFOO").exec(); // returns null
const cat2 = await Cat.findOne({ _id: "FOOFOO" }).exec(); // returns null
const cat3 = await Cat.findOne({ name: "Fluffy" }).exec(); // returns null
const cats = await Cat.find({name: "Fluffy"}).exec(); // returns []
```

The mongoose debug output for this shows that these queries are all resolving to

```bash
Mongoose: cats.findOne({ _id: null }, {})
```

or

```bash
Mongoose: cats.find({ name: null }, { projection: null })
```

instead of the expected

```bash
Mongoose: cats.findOne({ _id: "FOOFOO" }, {})
Mongoose: cats.find({ name: "Fluffy" }, {})
```

I can even create a cat and immediately search for the returned id and it returns `null`.

I've reviewed the documentation for multiple connections (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections) and felt that my factory functions were sufficient even though I am passing a connection rather than creating one in the factory function so that I can reuse it.

What's going on here? Hopefully this is enough detail but the example is contrived.